# how to get 3 highest value in 6 variable in php?

Tags: php

I have 6 variables and each of those have an integer assigned to them. Could anybody please let me know how I can get the 3 highest value from 6 variable which has the highest value? [edit] [i dont want using max(). this will only get highest value]

Comment: but that only got 1 highest value. i want 3. please advice me.

Comment: If you know to get the highest value, what hinders you from getting the second largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would use to achieve this:

```
$vars = array(10, 6, 89, 11, 4, 8); //Array with the integers. If you have separate variables I suggest you use: array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6);
rsort($vars);
echo $vars[0].", ".$vars[1].", ".$vars[2];
```

rsort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php
sorts from high to low without keeping key indexes.

Also, I don't understand why people mark this as duplicate, the linked questions are not the same as this one, even though its similar.

Comment: thanks. the order question all suggest me using max() but not rsot(). This is what i want. did i still duplicate question? :(

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be a duplicate question since its so easy to misunderstand as max only ;) @Artsylar